# Overwrite text file but not from The start

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, text

I'm trying to overwrite a text file which I know how to do, but I don't sant to start overwriting it from The beginning. Let's say I have a text file:

```
Ggh
Hello
Oi
The
See
```

I don't want to start overwriting it from Ggh. I want to start from Oi and make it into:

```
Ggh
Hello
Why
My
Hey
```

I don't want to search through The file and replace The words though since in my case i dont know The words.
Thank you

Comment: What's your criteria for where to start?

Comment: Open the file in `r+` mode. Read until you get to the place where you want to start writing. Write the new text. Call `file.truncate()` to remove anything after that.

Comment: I want to use a number which Will indicate The line

Comment: So if it's line 3, read the first 2 lines, then start writing like I said.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. It is important for the community that you *also* demonstrate that you are working to solve your issue. The best way to do that in my opinion is to include the **text** based version of the source code you have so far, even if it is not working quite right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to just read the first two lines and write them again. Then write the new lines after that.